# Need to produce regulated 5V from a source that ranges 3.7 - 6VDC

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

I'm building a device that will be solar powered and uses a microcontroller requiring 5VDC.  The solar charger emits anything from 3.7V (from it's Li-ion battery) up to 6.0 V (raw output from the solar panel.)

I understand that getting 5V from a *higher* voltage requires a voltage regulator, and that getting 5V from a *lower* voltage requires a buck converter.  But how do I get 5V from a source that produces 3.7 - 6.0 volts, depending upon whether the sun is shining?

Answer (score 2):

One approach I have used in a similar case is to use a boost converter to convert the input voltage to a voltage slightly higher than the output voltage. For example 6V in your case.

Then follow that with an LDO to drop the voltage to the 5V output voltage.

This is not quite as efficient as using a buck-boost converter but uses more easily available parts and the overall efficiency is still reasonable.

I used an LTC1949 for the boost converter and an LM2940 5V LDO linear regulator.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that getting 5V from a higher voltage requires a voltage regulator.

Yes, a buck converter or a linear regulator are both types of voltage regulators suitable for getting 5V from a higher voltage.

> getting 5V from a lower voltage requires a buck converter.

No, that would require a boost converter.

When you need a regulated output voltage from a source that can be above OR below the target output voltage, you need a non-inverting buck-boost regulator.

The graphic below from the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck%E2%80%93boost_converter) article on buck-boost converters shows the 4-switch topology that can buck or boost the input voltage as necessary to maintain the output voltage at the desired setpoint.

Per the comment below by Dean, a SEPIC converter can also work in this application.

[image]

Comment: Oh thanks yeah I meant to say "boost".

Comment: Or a SEPIC converter

Comment: @DeanFranks Yes, a SEPIC would work too.  Two inductors (can be on a common core) harder to compensate and all the load current has to pass through a capacitor, but has its advantages too.

Comment: Is the switch a literal switch for manually changing the mode or is that an abstraction?  That would not work in my case, because the voltage goes to 3.7 when there's no sun, and up to 6 when there is sun; it has to automatically know to  boost or drop the voltage.

Comment: @David No, the "switches" are transistors in practice, all automatically controlled by a controller IC.  You don't say how much current you need, but here's an example of a part that has all the switches built in, you just add the external passives: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps63070.pdf?ts=1651773768510

Comment: Thanks John, datasheet very helpful, I will read up on this.

Comment: Look on dedicated solution LTC3105 (https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc3105.html).

Comment: @Gregory My read is that the OP already has a charger hooked to a battery, and he's trying to convert that voltage to run a uC- He's not trying to charge a battery from a solar panel or do MPPT which is what your linked LT part does, not to mention it's a boost only.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solar charger device that outputs a regulated 4.4 V which then will go to a boost converter.  This should solve the problem.  https://www.adafruit.com/product/4755

Answer (score 0):

This isn’t an uncommon problem, often seen when you need to derive a 3.3V supply from a lithium cell (3.0-4.3V).  Buck/boost and SEPIC topologies are often used, also flyback although that’s not as popular because the output is typically the opposite polarity from the input.  Alternatively a coupled inductor can be used to give an isolated output.